# How to make projects show in Python Spyder Project Explorer

Tags: python, spyder

My Spyder Project Explorer normally shows a project and its files, but I recently deleted a project and made the project explorer space empty. I am trying to make the Project Explorer show my existing projects or a new project, but when i try to do that it gives me the error "Project not a Spyder project". How can i restore my Spyder project explorer to show existing or new projects?

Answer (score 14):

You need to go to the `Projects` menu, and select the option called `New Project`.

Then you need to select the option called `Existing directory`, choose the directory where your project is located at in the `Location` field and finally press `Create`.

That will automatically show your project in the Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was :-created apps and project were not visible on pydev explorer.
I resolved it by right clicking on project->pydev->remove .pyc files.(cleanup).And then i was able to see created apps in my eclipse under project.

[image]