# importing and existing project in spyder using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

i have an existing project and want to import , compile and run it through spyder. It results in error that the project is not a spyder project when i run it. I am a newbie and not getting any solution over the internet.

Comment: what is a project? do you mean a script? a module? a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @PaulH it's a folder having multiple python scripts. I just downloaded it to practice how the files are compiled . It is a complete ananconda environment

Comment: anaconda environments are not simply "folder[s] having multiple scripts"

Comment: This answer worked for me: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452958/how-to-make-projects-show-in-python-spyder-project-explorer>